# not all attributes defined in __init__?

Tags: python

I've seen the following code.

```
class Primes:    

   def __init__(self, max):       
       self.max = max        
       self.number = 1

   def __iter__(self):       
       return self

   def __next__(self):        
       self.number += 1        
       if self.number >= self.max:           
           raise StopIteration        
       elif check_prime(self.number):            
           return self.number        
       else:            
           return self.__next__()
```

In the dunder init function, we set `self.number=1`, without having included earlier the attribute `number`. What's the meaning of it?

Comment: it simply initialises the `number` property of the object to the value 1.

Comment: What do you mean, "not all attributes defined in `__init__`"? It's defined right there, in `__init__`: `self.number = 1`.

Comment: Were you under the impression that attributes had to correspond directly to `__init__` arguments? There's no such connection.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes that's exactly what I thought. That if you call `self.arg`, then `arg` must have been defined in `__init__(self,..., arg,...)`.

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, only means that `self.number` is not customizable and will always values `1` when creating an instance of `Primes`. This is used when the class need an attribute, which will be used along its state and methods, but it's value should always be the same when instanciating the object

```
def __init__(self, max):       
    self.max = max        
    self.number = 1
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Why though is not defined like max in `__init__`?

Comment: @user430191 just that : `max` should be configurable, `number` should not